# Restrict ibm_security_logout?logoutExitPage parameter

Tags: websphere-8

I am working on an application running on IBM Websphere 8.0.
Whenever I append `ibm_security_logout?logoutExitPage=<any other website or domain>`, the session gets terminated and the user is redirected to the other website.

I am fine with session getting destroyed, but I do not want the user to be redirected to any other website mentioned after the `logoutExitPage` parameter.

Could anyone help me with this?

Let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you applied the latest fix pack. This was fixed in the 8.0.0.1, which only allowed pages from the same website. If you need to go to external sites you have to configure following paramters:

> By default the URL to the logout page should point to the host to which the request was made or its domain. Otherwise, a generic logout page is displayed. If you need to point this URL to a different host, then you need to set the `com.ibm.websphere.security.logoutExitPageDomainList` property in the security.xml file with a list of URLs that are allowed for the logout page. You can choose to allow any logout exit page to be used by setting the `com.ibm.websphere.security.allowAnyLogoutExitPageHost` property to a value of true. Setting this property to true might open your systems to a potential URL redirect attacks.

For more details check [Customizing web application login](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/it/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_pofolo.html)